# check if the string equals the first letters of a list of words

Tags: python, string, matching, text-processing

I am confused about a simple task

the user will give me a string and my program will check if this string equals the first letters of a list of words ( like this example)

```py
>>> html_attr = ["onerror","onload"]
>>> example_task(html_attr,"on")
["onerror","onload"]
>>> example_task(html_attr,"one")
["onerror"]
```

should I use fuzzywuzzy here or what ?

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No need for some weird libraries, Python has a nice builtin str function called `startswith` that does just that.

```
def example_task(words, beginning):
    return [w for w in words if w.startswith(beginning)]
```

Fuzzywuzzy would come in handy if you don't want an exact match.